# length of array at runtime in C++

Tags: c++, runtime, variable-length-array

I have been asked to prove that one can set the array length in the program, and it does not need to be determined at compile time. I have following code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x, myarray[x];
    cout << "Enter the size of array" << endl;
    cin >> x;
        }
```

But when I compile, I get the following errors:

```
error C2057: expected constant expression
 error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
 error C2133: 'myarray' : unknown size
```

I'm not sure what the right way to approach it.

Comment: You can't prove that because array sizes have to be compile time constants.

Comment: What does `x` actually contain, when you say `myarray[x]`?!?

Comment: ***int x, myarray[x];*** Even if C++ had variable length arrays. You do realize that x is not initialized here..

Answer (score 1):

int matrix[x];
i dont think c++ does not support  that kind of declaration. use new[] operator if you want to dynamically allocate memory for an array